# Cannot download System.Data.Sqlite via Nuget in VS2015

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to download package System.Data.Sqlite with EF6 support via stock NuGet in Visual Studio 2015 Community. After pressing "Install", I'm getting asked for dependencies. Then, after confirming, nothing happens for a while and then, in the Output window, I get "Object reference not set to instance of object" error. I upgraded NuGet to 3.2.x, but the problem persists. What can I do to resolve it?

---

**Edit:** Log from Output console:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'System.Data.SQLite.1.0.98.1' with respect to project 'WPTManager', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'System.Data.SQLite.1.0.98.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'System.Data.SQLite.1.0.98.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'System.Data.SQLite.1.0.98.1'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' does not exist in project 'WPTManager'
Package 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' does not exist in folder 'D:\Dokumenty\Dev\VS\Projekty\WPTManager\packages'
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.GlobalPackagesFolderUtility.<AddPackageAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DownloadResourceV3.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageDownloader.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: Which package exactly?

Comment: @ErikEJ System.Data.SQLite.1.0.98.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround.

1. Install Entity Framework via NuGet;
2. Now install System.Data.SQLite - it will install correctly.

No direct solution though - most likely it's a bug in NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. So I downloaded package manually from NuGet site, then I've set my own package source and it was installed correctly from there. It is also only workaround like yours.